# jQuery function does not get called for Html Helpers but gets called for it's equivalent html controls

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a beginner in asp.net MVC.

I am using MVC 4 for my project and I am using strongly typed partial view and I render it in a View.

What I am trying to achieve is when a user enters a email address in Email Address textbox which is generated by  **@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Email)**
*Html helper* and when user looses focus on that textbox; a **jQuery** function 
**focusout** will get called which will check if entered Email is already present in a database or not. Following is my code

```
@model PITCRoster.tblLoginDetail
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddUser","Resources",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>tblLoginDetail</legend>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Email)

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <p id="emailVerify"></p>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPassword)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>    
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and I have a jQuery function which is as follows

```
 $("#Email").focusout(function () {

        var emailData = $("#Email").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Resources/CheckEmailAddress',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: '{emailId:"' + emailData + '"}',
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (data) {
                alert('something went wrong!');
            }
        });

        function OnSuccess(data) {
            debugger;
            if (!data) {
                $("#emailVerify").css('color', 'green');
                $("#emailVerify").html("Valid Email!");
            }

            if (data) {
                $("#emailVerify").css('color', 'red');
                $("#emailVerify").html("Email already registered!");
            }
        }
    });
```

The jQuery function doesn't get called for the **textbox** created by **Html Helper**

But when I replace that Html helper with following code it runs properly.

```
 <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="email" class="text-box single-line" name="Email" value="" id="Email" data-val-required="The Email field is required." data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val="true" />

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
```

`CheckEmailAddress` is a method in Resources controller.

Can anybody help me out why jQuery function doesn't get called when I use `@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Email)`?

Comment: Can you show the generate HTML of `@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Email)`?

Comment: Why not use the built in `[Remote]` attribute?

Comment: @Satpal ' <input type="email" class="text-box single-line" name="Email" value="" id="EmailId" data-val-required="The Email field is required." data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val="true" />' 
It is same as I used in lateral code

Comment: @StephenMuecke I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Your code does not make sense - `@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Email)` generates a textbox with `id="Email"` but you claim that when you do it manually with `id="EmailId"` it works - but it cant because the functions is `$("#Email").focusout()` not `$("#EmailId").focusout()`. Can you check the code you have posted is correct.

Comment: Also refer this article [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ahh! Sorry for wrong id. It should be id="Email"

Comment: If it is id="Email", then your jquery function should fire..Put an alert in .focusout event and see what happens..

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id and type to your model. By default it doesn't have an id of `Email`

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new {type="email", id="Email"})
```

Comment: Of course it has `id="Email"` - the html helper does that

Comment: @wannaCSharp When Html helper renders it in browser it automatically has id="email"